# Get App connected users from Google+ collections [Connected collection / not Visible collection]

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-signin

I want to use app connected google users who are user's friends.
I am not getting results using this API:

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/connected

and passing API key, access token. But still I am not getting results.

I used in iOS app via iOS Google Sign-In SDK.

Can you help me, if any parameter is missing, or any procedure is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This is still an open issue.. I am also facing the same issue.. But luckily we have option to use `visible` instead of `connected` in API. But this is temporary solution to use.
There is an open issue
refer :  https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=736